# HTML autocomplete/snippets stopped working when I changed the file language type to `HTML (EEx)` for a .html.eex file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I guess there's some built in snippets because I used to be able to do stuff like type: `h2` + `tab` and get `<h2>|</h2>`. However my language snippets weren't working, so I switched the file language type to `HTML (EEx)`, for `.html.eex` files. Now my language snippets work (from a package), but now I don't get any HTML snippets. Is there a way to tell VSCode to treat `.html.eex` files as if they were HTML files? I sort of want to merge the `HTML` and `HTML (EEx)`  language file types into one. What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "HTML (EEx)": "html"
},
```

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work anymore. I had to use:

```"html-eex": "html"```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings.json

```
"files.associations": {
      "*.html": "html",
      "*.html.eex": "html"
}
```

Comment: That works to get the HTML snippets working, but now the EEx snippets don't work.